# forward declaration of enum in base class, definition in derived class

Tags: c++11, enums, forward-declaration

So, I am trying to define an enum in a derived class where the declaration is in the base class. It looks something like this:

```
class A {
    public:
    enum class E;
    virtual int foo () = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    enum class E { C, D };
    int foo () {
        E e = E::C;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A *a = &b;
    a->foo();
}
```

This will work (compiler gcc 4.8, compile command: g++ -std=c++11 ...) however I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, so that I don't have to write E:: everytime I have to use the enum.

edit: I mistakenly thought this works, however, this is not really a forward declartion but two distinct enum class A::E and B::E

Comment: *that I don't have to write E:: everytime I have to use the enum* -- then use old `enum` instead of `enum class`.

Comment: Why do you need declaration in base class?

Comment: does that forward even do anything? you state that there is a A::E, which you then don't use. that is probably unrelated to the B::E you then define

Comment: @sp2danny yes it seems you are correct. What ways are there to forward declare an enum in a base class and define it in a derived class?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus 

I need it so that other derived classes can define E their own way.

Comment: none, as far as I know. Types aren't virtual.

Comment: @burnedWood: but... why? Why do you need to have "virtual `enum`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, so that I don't have to write E:: everytime I have to use the enum.

This is unrelated to forward declaration. You have to write `E::`, because you use `enum class`.
If you don't want this, use old `enum` instead:

```
class B : public A {
    public:
    enum E { C, D };
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, how could I forward declare an old enum? I need the forward declaration so that other derived classes can define E however they like.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish.  An `enum` defines a type, so each time you define an `enum` you define a new type.  Those types have no relations between them, in contrast to classes which are one of the few types that do have relations between them.

So, if you have the two following classes,

```
class A {

  public:

    enum class E {
      X,
      Y
    };

 };

class B : public A {

  public:

    enum class E {
      V,
      W
    };

 };
```

The types `A::E` and `B::E` are distinct types.  Regardless of the class hierarchy, there's isn't any relation between them.